# Rendering an amp document in a shell page

Tags: amp-html, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to render an amp doc similar to https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/amp-in-pwa/#6

When I do

```
fetchDocument(url).then(function(doc) {
        // Let AMP take over and render the page
        var ampedDoc = AMP.attachShadowDoc(container, doc, url);
        ampedDoc.close();

    });
```

the amp doc (fetched from url) is placed in the container but amp-tags are not rendered.

For example: `amp-img` tag is in the sources but it does not render as an img tag in the way "Googe Search" does when it renders that doc.

**Question**: Is there a way to render amp-components when loading amp documents with `https://cdn.ampproject.org/shadow-v0.js`

Comment: Did you try checking your implementation with the [AMP Validator](https://validator.ampproject.org/) for debugging?

Comment: @noogui my amp document is valid. When showed in google search, everything works great

Answer (score 0):

AMP components such as amp-img should render inside an app shell. Without a code snippet it's hard say what's goes wrong in your case. Here are two things you can do to find the problem:

1. Check the javascript console for error messages.
2. Checkout and run [the code lab sample](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/amp-pwa/tree/master/step6) and see if it works:. If yes, compare it with your own implementation.